# Reference a Cell value from another Cell (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Worksheet (MasterData) that contains the value "J" in cell B1.  In cell C1, I have the value "10".  With that information, I want to access another worksheets and get the value from cell J10.  However I can't do something like:

```
myValue = Sheets("MySheet").Cells(Sheets("MasterData").Cells("B1").Value & Sheets("MasterData").Cells("C1").Value)
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
myValue = Sheets("MySheet").Range( _
       Sheets("MasterData").Range("B1").Value _
     & Sheets("MasterData").Range("C1").Value _
).Value
```

Comment: You're welcome. Now if you could select the posting (or avb's, it is also correct) as the right answer to the question, that'd be great. :-)

Comment: Yeah no problem, had to wait 5 minutes ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try
`myValue = Sheets("AnotherSheet").Range(Sheets("MySheet").Cells(Sheets("MasterData").Cells("B1").Value & Sheets("MasterData").Cells("C1").Value))`